# Strip double quotes from list

Tags: python, csv, sage

I'm using sage, python and CSV.

Here is an example row from my csv file:

```
"(4, 4)",0.921,1.512,1.718,"[[(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]]","[[(0, 0, 3), (1, 0, 0)]]"
```

I also have:

```
with open('log.csv', 'rt') as logFile:
    logreader = csv.reader(logFile)
    for row in logreader:
        a = row[3]
        b = row[4]
```

I was expecting `csv.reader` to strip the double-quotes when assigning `a` and `b` such that:

```
a == [[(0, 0.5, 1), (1, 0, 0)]]
b == [[(0, 0, 3), (1, 0, 0)]]
```

however

```
a == "[[(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]]"
b == "[[(0, 0, 3), (1, 0, 0)]]"
```

What is the best way to achieve what I was expecting?
Thanks

Comment: To anyone that is having this problem when using sage, make sure that all numbers are either `int` or `float`, NOT `rational`. This should fix things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to parse the strings into lists:

```
from ast import literal_eval
with open('log.csv', 'rt') as logFile:
    logreader = csv.reader(logFile)
    for row in logreader:
        a = literal_eval(row[3])
        b = literal_eval(row[4])
```

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("[[(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]]")
[[(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]]
>>> type(literal_eval("[[(0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0)]]"))
<class 'list'>
>>>
```

Comment: I tried using literal_eval but got `ValueError: malformed string`, I believe this is to do with having Sage Rationals in the tuples.
Thanks for your help

Comment: @TheRef - Yes, that is the cause.  If you look at the documentation for `ast.literal_eval`, you will see that it can only parse strings, bytes, numbers (which are ints, floats, and complex), tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.  In other words, it can only handle the basic Python datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the built-in strip function:

```
a = row[3].strip('"')
b = row[4].strip('"')
```